# Spring Jersey JSON POJO Serialization issue

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jersey

I am developing a Rest API for my Spring Project. For this I have been using  Jersey.

My Controller Looks as follows:

```
@Path("movies")
@Component
public class MovieController {

  @Autowired
  MoviesService moviesService;

  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Response getAll(@QueryParam("count") int rowsPerPage, @QueryParam("page") int page){

      PaginationResponse<List<Movie>> response = moviesService.getList(page,rowsPerPage);
      if(response==null){
          return Response.noContent().build();
      }
      return Response.ok(response).build();
  }
}
```

However when calling this method the return is the following.

```
{"content":["ar.edu.itba.paw2018b.models.Movie@1f6c00ef"],"hasNext":true,"hasPrevious":false}
```

**For some reason the Movie POJO is seemingly serialized through a call to Object's toString() method which is clearly not a JSON representation of the Movie Object.**

Below are the extracts of the Movie and PaginationResponse classes.

Movie Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movie {
  @Column(name = "image")
  private byte[] img;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "movies_movieid_seq", name = "movies_movieid_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "movieid", nullable = false)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String name;

  @Column
  private double rating;

  @Column(name = "releasedate", columnDefinition="DATE")
  private Date releaseDate;

  @Column
  private int runtime;

  @Column
  private String genres;

  @Column
  private boolean active;

  @Column
  private String trailer;

  @Column
  private String summary;

  @Column
  private String director;

  @Column
  private String actors;

  @Column
  private String restriction;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Screening> screenings;

  public Movie(){}

  public Movie(long id, String name, float rating, Date releaseDate, int runtime, String genres, byte[] img, String trailer,
             String summary, String director, String actors, String restriction){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.runtime = runtime;
    this.genres = genres;
    this.img = img;
    this.active = true;
    this.trailer= trailer;
    this.summary = summary;
    this.director = director;
    this.actors = actors;
    this.restriction = restriction;
  }
//Getters and Setters for all properties
}
```

PaginationResponse class

```
public class PaginationResponse<T extends List> {
  private boolean hasNext;
  private boolean hasPrevious;
  private T content;

  public interface Paginageable<T>{
      T getData(int querySize, int queryStart);
  }

  public PaginationResponse(int page, int rowsPerPage, Paginageable<T> paginageable)
  {
      fetchPage(page, rowsPerPage, paginageable);
  }

  public PaginationResponse(){}

  public PaginationResponse(boolean hasNext, boolean hasPrevious, T content) {
    this.hasNext = hasNext;
    this.hasPrevious = hasPrevious;
    this.content = content;
  }

  public void fetchPage(int page, int rowsPerPage, Paginageable<T> paginageable)
  {
      int start = page*rowsPerPage;
      boolean hasPrevious=true;
      boolean hasNext = false;


      if(start<0){
          this.hasNext=true;
          this.hasPrevious=false;
          this.content=null;
          return;
      }

      int queryStart = start -1;
      int querySize = rowsPerPage + 2;

      if(queryStart<0){
          hasPrevious=false;
          queryStart = start;
          querySize = rowsPerPage +1;
      }

      T content = paginageable.getData(querySize, queryStart);

      if(content.size()==querySize){
          hasNext=true;
          content.remove(content.size()-1);
      }
      if(hasPrevious){
          if(content.isEmpty())
          {
            hasPrevious=false;
          }
          else{
            content.remove(0);
          }
      }

      this.hasNext=hasNext;
      this.hasPrevious=hasPrevious;
      this.content=content;
  }
//Getters and Setters for all properties
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="paw2018b"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <display-name>TicketCentral</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        ar.edu.itba.paw2018b.webapp.config.WebConfig,
        ar.edu.itba.paw2018b.webapp.config.WebAuthConfig,
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ar.edu.itba.paw2018b.webapp.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>ROOT</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



  <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>ROOT</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: i think you are missing setters and getters of `Movie` class

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed them from the post for convenience. Added a comment to clarify

Comment: Use Jackson as your JSON provider.

Answer (score -1):

Try to override toString() method in Movie class and then your response json will be properly formed.